ArcGIS TIFF JPEG compression versus GDAL
I am using both ArcGIS Pro and GDAL to handle raster data and I noticed that ArcGIS Pro can do JPEG compression on large TIFF file (I had no problem with a 322628x322628 TIFF) but the GDAL JPEG encoder is limited to 65536x65536.
Can someone explain how ArcGIS Pro can use JPEG compression on a large TIFF? Is there a way to enable GDAL to do the same?

Such large files are typically best created with creation option -co TILED=YES, otherwise it will be slow to use it afterwards. Can you try that? More info in the gdal documentation

@Pieter does it creates tiles as output? If yes, then it's not a solution. Anyway such big tiff are not slow to use if you create the pyramids...

it creates one file, but within that file the data is saved in tiles. So, in combination with pyramids, if you zoom to the deepest level, only the tiles within the file needed for your region of interest need to be read/uncompressed instead of the entire file.

Most likely arcgis pro will create them like that by default, in gdal you need to specify it...

ok thank you for the info! Thats a nice thing to know!

@Pieter do you know if ArcGIS Pro is using GDAL under the hood for that?

ArcGIS Pro using GDAL under hood, no idea if that is the case, I doubt it... but I meant that most likely  it will create the geotiffs "tiled" by default... Most likely you'll be able to check this in "properties" of the file or something like that...

Are you mixing the JPEG format and JPEG compressed TIFF format? Corresponding GDAL drivers are https://gdal.org/en/latest/drivers/raster/jpeg.html and https://gdal.org/en/latest/drivers/raster/gtiff.html. JPEG image can't of course be  bigger than 65535×65535 pixels because that is the limit of the JPEG format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG.

Yes ArcGIS uses gdal internally and has since version 10.0. There's no mention of a JPEG compression limit in the GDAL GTiff docs so as long as your gtiff is internally tiled  with tile size less than 65536x65536 (ArcGIS default is 128x128 or 256x256 tile size, I can't remember exactly) you will be fine

See https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/10751. The JPEG size limit has actually an effect also on the GDAL GeoTIFF driver when the output is not tiled. In the next GDAL version there will be a warning "COMPRESS=JPEG is only compatible of un-tiled images whose width is lesser or equal to 65500 pixels" or for tiled images "COMPRESS=JPEG is only compatible of tiled images whose BLOCKXSIZE is lesser or equal to 65500 pixels". The same applies to BLOCKYSIZE.
